# Get Current Place using Google Place API

Tags: android, google-api, location

I'm writing an application where trying to fetch current place using [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place). But I'm getting following error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(20212): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use the API required for this call.
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzb(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli.zza(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzj.getCurrentPlace(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at ala.youngashram.droid.com.ala.ALaActivity.getCurrentLocation(ALaActivity.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at ala.youngashram.droid.com.ala.ALaActivity.onConnected(ALaActivity.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzh(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlg.zznU(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlg.onConnected(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzpf(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestion what I'm missing here, what I need to configure to get this!

**Updated Working Code:** Thanks @ProblemSlover for Sharing [link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start).

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

This is for connection request:

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

and following to get location, call it once you connected successfully:

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {

                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : placeLikelihoods) {
                    log(String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                }

                placeLikelihoods.release();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Also, posting a code snippet would have been helpful.

Comment: @ProblemSlover Thanks..and it worked..I was missing **addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)** call while setting up GoogleApiClient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please show us the code you use to configure GoogleApiClient. Please make sure it's done in the proper way as described in the section "Connect to the Places API" on the getting started page. https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start
Here is The config snipped:

```
// Your activity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your activity, and call it in your onCreate method

```
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new MapCallback())
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new FailedCallback())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Chitti, shared [link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start) hint worked for me.